# Forwarding attributes from parent directive to child element in AngularJS 1.4.x

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Hi SO my experience with angularJS is fairly lackluster, I've tried reading the documentation and searched around without a lot of results. I am tasked with maintaining a legacy angularJS app that utilizes angularJS 1.4.x, grunt and typescript.

I have a directive for populating and handling a Yes-No select list, this select list is marked with the attribute `kendo-drop-down-list` I have a need to forward attributes from this directive to the select element due to the way validation works in this project.

This is my usage of the Yes-No dropdown

```
<yes-no-drop-down ..scopedattributes... 
    data-validationRule1-msg="This is rule 1 that failed"
    data-validationRule2-msg="This is rule 2 that failed"
/>
```

Inside the yes-no-drop-down directive the scope specify the scopedattributes

```js
scope: IYesNoDropDownControllerScope = {
        selectedoption: "=",
        disabled: "=?",
        name: "@",
    }
```

The template for the dropdown is the following

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
        ... k-xx attributes for kendo ...
        name="{{vm.name}}"   
        >
</select>
```

My issue is that the attribute `data-validationRuleXYZ-msg` is variable depending on the validation rule(s) that runs. and I need to forward theese attributes to the select. so I end up with this result

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
        name="TestYesNoDropdown"   
    data-validationRule1-msg="This is rule 1 that failed"
    data-validationRule2-msg="This is rule 2 that failed"
        >
</select>
```